# Disable NAT and have a direct WAN - LAN connection with just one PC?

Tags: networking, router, lan, nat

I have a pretty old router which is behaving rather weird with UDP port forwarding (Seems to be blocking/not routing incoming connections). I need it to behave such that the cable is directly connected to a single PC (No NAT). I know I could instead connect it directly to the PC but I need to be able to share that Internet Connection through the PC (only 1 lan port on PC). Can such a setup work?

Comment: NAT routers are supposed to block incoming connections (both UDP & TCP), unless you've configured it otherwise.

Comment: Well, I made a mistake explaining. If I try initiating an openvpn session (udp port), no reply seems to be coming back through the router (checked the logs and the requests do reach the server). Have no such problem when I connect directly to PC. I didn't know what to call them, other than incoming connections.